# How to optimize parameters binding from blade to Vue component's children?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, components, laravel-blade

having in blade a directive for a parent component like this:

```
<component  v-bind:mydata="data"  v-bind:basepathimg="{{config('base_path_images')}}"   ></component>
```

Which in turns loads multiple times its children like:

```
<div v-for="(c, index) in mydata">
 <childcomponent v-bind:c="item" v-bind:basepathimg="basepathimg" ></childcomponent>
</div>

....

<script>
export default{
    props: ['mydata', 'basepathimg', ....],
....
```

then finally in child component

```
<img :src="basepathimg"  class="img-responsive">


<script>
export default{
    props: ['item', 'basepathimg', ....],
....
```

Focus here is on "basepathimg" As you see it has to be passthrough blade parentcomponent ant then child component... but actually I don't need it in parent component.

Could I optimize this some way?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a javascript variable in the blade:

```
<script>
window.Paths = {
    img: "{{ config('base_path_images') }}"
};
</script>
```

And then create a computed property in the component

```
export default {
    computed: {
        basepathimg () {
            return window.Paths.img;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Then i think you have to pass it through the parent component